# BERTopic: Kernel keeps restarting in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, kernel, jupyter-lab

I have a large dataset of roughly 7M sentences. I'm working in Jupyter Lab and I'm trying to run BERTopic to analyze the data. I have the following code:

```
from bertopic import BERTopic

# Train Model
bert_model = BERTopic(verbose=True, calculate_probabilities=True)
topics, probs = bert_model.fit_transform(flat_data_words)
```

I tried to run it twice already, but every time the Kernel restarts. The first time it happened when it was at around 70-75% of the batches. I tried to restart everything and re-run the code. It reached 100%, but then the Kernel restarted again while "fitting the dimensionality algorithm". This is the output I'm getting:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tqdm/auto.py:21: TqdmWarning: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
  from .autonotebook import tqdm as notebook_tqdm
2024-01-22 18:44:02,933 - BERTopic - Embedding - Transforming documents to embeddings.
Batches: 100%|████████████████████████| 233737/233737 [2:09:34<00:00, 30.06it/s]
2024-01-22 20:57:06,204 - BERTopic - Embedding - Completed ✓
2024-01-22 20:57:06,223 - BERTopic - Dimensionality - Fitting the dimensionality reduction algorithm
```

I have no idea what might be the cause or how to solve the issue.

Comment: maybe the kernel uses too much memory and gets terminated by the operating system?

Comment: Looks like that might be the case. Is there a workaround? A way to reduce memory use or something like that?